# AngularJS Route loading error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

I wondered if you could help.

I am learning AngularJS and have decided to make use of the Angular Route lib.
I keep getting an error when trying to load it.

```
 angular.js:38Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0/$injector/modulerr?p0=jargonBuster&p1=Err…loudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.3.0%2Fangular.min.js%3A18%3A3)
```

Here is my code, I have changed up the links to the see what works with no enjoy.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app = "jargonBuster">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Angular.js Example</title>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular-route.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <section ng-controller="MainCtrl"></section><!-- VIEW -->
</body>
</html>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('jargonBuster', ['ngRoute']); 

//router
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/', {
        templateUrl:'keyword-list.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
    }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
});


// The Controller
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("getdecks.php").success(function(data) { //Gets data from The Decks Table
        $scope.deckData = data;});
    $http.get("getcards.php").success(function(data) { //Gets data from The Cards Table
        $scope.cardsData = data;});

    $scope.sortField = 'keyword';   
    $scope.reverse = true;

});// End of the controller
```

Thanks, any ideas?

Comment: remove `ng-controller="MainCtrl"` from html

Comment: Also another observation. Your script that loads `angular-route` is `1.3.14` but your main angular script is `1.3.0`. Try changing the script for angular.js to `1.3.14`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is actually your html markup. If you change it from

```
<section ng-controller="MainCtrl"></section>
```

to

```
<section ng-view></section>
```

You should see the template loading (provided other errors don't crop up down stream in your keyword-list.html file which you didn't provide.

I set up your code with a simple keyword-list.html file of my own and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

you putting you script that holds definition outside the html

you may try this order

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app = "jargonBuster">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Angular.js Example</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>


</head>
<body>
<section ng-controller="MainCtrl"></section><!-- VIEW -->

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You actually don't need to do this. It's way more common to have your js scripts in the head tag, unless the scripts are for fancy animations.

Comment: the related issue through there is the script that holds module is define outside html

Comment: Now I see what you mean when you said his script was outside the html, I didn't notice he put it all the way at the bottom of the file. He should put his own js scripts after the angular js scripts in the head tag

Comment: but why should i put my scripts in head tag, iam always try to load Html elements first and let the js do its thing after page render ?

Comment: I guess it depends on what kind of code you write. I usually interpolate at least a few things on any given page. Even when using ng-cloak to try and prevent that weird split second flash where {{interpolate_me}} is visible on the page, the flash will still happen if your js script tag is in the body. Granted, this isn't a page breaking situation, just seems better from a user experience perspective to not have that happen.

Answer (score -1):

You are loading 2 different versions of angular and I believe they are conflicting. Your `angular-route.js`script is a newer version than your `angular.js` script. Try updating it to below.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```